# Making a relaxing LEGO tub

Tags: design

I'd like to make a few tubs with an ornate gold-trimmed look.  I'd like to get atleast a somewhat curved feel to them, not just the blocky square ones you see on the youtube tutorials.  Here's a few of the pieces I'm considering:

- [shorts for the bathers](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=970c00pb0539&C=0#T=S&C=80&O=%7B%22color%22:80,%22st%22:%224%22,%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22100%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D)
- [bare chest](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=973pb1091c01&C=0#T=S&C=3&O=%7B%22color%22:3,%22st%22:%224%22,%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22100%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D), or similar for the bathers
- [inverted arch](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=70681&C=86#T=S&C=86&O=%7B%22color%22:%2286%22,%22st%22:%224%22,%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22100%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D)  for the curved base of the tub
  or
  [double concave brick](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=99301&name=Slope%2033%203%20x%203%20Double%20Concave&category=%5BSlope%5D#T=S&C=59&O=%7B%22color%22:%2259%22,%22st%22:%224%22,%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22100%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D)  and other 33-Degree bricks for the base of the tub
  or
  [Tall inverted arch](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=18653&C=4#T=S&C=4&O=%7B%22color%22:%224%22,%22st%22:%224%22,%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22100%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D)  for the curved base. (I like this one because it comes in orange which is closer to the pearl gold pieces)
- [2x2 macaroni](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3063&name=Brick,%20Round%20Corner%202%20x%202%20Macaroni%20with%20Stud%20Notch&category=%5BBrick,%20Round%5D#T=S&C=115&O=%7B%22color%22:%22115%22,%22st%22:%224%22,%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22100%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D)
  and
  [macaroni tile](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=27925&name=Tile,%20Round%20Corner%202%20x%202%20Macaroni&category=%5BTile,%20Round%5D#T=S&C=115&O=%7B%22color%22:%22115%22,%22st%22:%224%22,%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22100%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D) to top it off with a nice pearl gold finish.
- [mirror](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=92747pb11&C=15#T=S&C=15&O=%7B%22color%22:15,%22st%22:%224%22,%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22100%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D) on the wall for a decorative finish
- [faucet](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=13770&C=115#T=S&C=115&O=%7B%22color%22:%22115%22,%22st%22:%224%22,%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22100%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D)

My concern is that It's not going to quite have the 'rounded' look that I want, particularly on the outside.  Do you folks have any suggestions for improving this design?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both of these designs use the same faucet piece and legs can be easily attached beneath, the issue with most of these designs is that parts are mostly in white as those parts are more common than gold. If you are set on the colour you will be fairly limited in terms of pieces but there are some [ways to change the colour of bricks](https://www.brothers-brick.com/2013/06/30/50-shades-of-bley-iain-heaths-mad-lego-science/) with some limitations.

This design by [Elspeth De Montes](https://www.flickr.com/photos/azurebrick/28353510322/) uses the (Studs not on top) techniques to get that smooth look without any exposed studs on the top. It uses a 1 x 2 x 5 brick

[image]

This design by [Ryan Smith](https://www.flickr.com/photos/ryanthescooterguy/49685086516/) has a similar shape but with studs on top.

[image]

You might find more relevant designs by searching on [Flickr](https://www.flickr.com/search/?text=lego%20bath) rather Google images for example.

Comment: It is so handy that LEGO water doesn't spill over the edge of the tub and drench the people on the floor below you. :)

Comment: Is the 2nd one full of blood?

Comment: @ChrisH Yes, but look at those lovely curves though.

Comment: Oh yes, it's very nicely done.  There are a  few vampire minifigs that would go well with it